# Batch gradient descent algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I learned the Batch gradient descent algorithm recently and tried implementing it in Python. I used a data set which is not random. When I tried running the below code, the process is converging after 3 iterations but with a big error. Can someone guide me in a right way?
Sample Data set:(original data set length is 600.)

```
6203.75 1   173.8   43.6    0.0 183.0
6329.75 1   115.0   60.1    0.0 236.2
5830.75 1   159.5   94.1    21.0    275.8
4061.75 1   82.5    45.0    11.0    75.7
3311    1   185.5   46.1    4.0 0.0
4349.75 1   169.5   40.3    5.0 73.5
5695.25 1   138.5   68.9    6.0 204.2
5633.5  1   50.0    117.3   4.0 263.9
```

First column is the output. Second column is the constant value. Rest are features.

Thank you

```
data = open('Data_trial.txt','r')
import time
lines=data.readlines()
dataSet=[]
for line in lines:                       
    dataSet.append(line.split())
original_output=[]
features=[]
for i in range(0,len(dataSet)):
    features.append([])
predict=[]
grad=[]
weights=[0,0,0,0,0]
learning_factor=0.01
for i in range(0,len(dataSet)):
    for j in range(0,len(dataSet[i])):
        if j==0:
            original_output.append(float(dataSet[i][j]))
        else:
            features[i].append(float(dataSet[i][j]))
def prediction(predict,weights,original_output,features):
    for count in range(0,len(original_output)):
        predict.append(sum(weights[i]*features[count][i] for i in range(0,len(features[count]))))
    print("predicted values",predict)

def gradient(predict,grad,original_output,features):
    for count in range(0,len(weights)):
        grad.append(sum((predict[i]-original_output[i])*features[i][count]
                        for i in range(0,len(original_output))))
    print("Gradient values",grad)
def weights_update(grad,learning_factor,weights):
    for i in range(0,len(weights)):
        weights[i]-=learning_factor*grad[i]
    print("Updated weights",weights)    
if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        prediction(predict,weights,original_output,features)
        gradient(predict,grad,original_output,features)
        weights_update(grad,learning_factor,weights)
        time.sleep(1)
        predict=[]
        grad=[]
        print()
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message? Maybe it's me, but I don't see where you calculate the gradient... It also seems you are more convenient in a programming language other than Python - looks like C. It might be good to first learn more about Python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I mean error, it's not a runtime error but the error of the value prediction. And about the gradient, I am calculating it where the Summ part is calculated in the program(Now, I have commented  it in the code.

Comment: Either I don't get it or this very odd way of calculating is not resulting in the gradient `G(x) = ( df/dx1 , df/dx2 , ... , df/dxn )`, where a certain component in a certain point `df/x1(xc) ~ (f(xc_1+h, xc_2, ..., xc_n) - f(xc_1-h, xc_2, ..., xc_n)) / 2h` with `h -> 0`. So you somewhere need to calculate a difference and a division, which both I don't see in your code.

Comment: @SvenKrüger http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex3/ex3.html take a look at this link.

Comment: Please improve this code by using functions with useful names, variables with useful names, numpy arrays (which improve the readability, number of loops and runtime) and [existing functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html).

Comment: And while I don't see which values should or would actually converge to which values, the most probable problem is the high learning rate of 10%. Reducing this should improve the gradient descent.

Comment: @YSelf Convergence of Weight values is what I was checking for! I have tried changing the learning rate also. I will comment in the code about deferent parts for readability and update it.

Comment: Please don't add comments, but change variable names. `a, W, W1, Summ, Summ1` are horrible variable names, since what does `W -= a*Summ` do? Just changing that to `weights -= learning_rate * gradient` would improbe the readability.

Comment: @YSelf made the suggested changes. I hope the code is more readable now. Please help me with the algorithm corrections. Thank you.

Comment: @YSelf  If you can still take a look at this mate!